# Scala code bubble sort for loop

Tags: algorithm, scala, sorting

```
object BubbleSort {
  def main(args : Array[String]) : Unit = {
    bubbleSort(Array(50,33,62,21,100)) foreach println
  }
  def bubbleSort(a:Array[Int]):Array[Int]={
    for(i<- 1 to a.length-1){
      for(j <- (i-1) to 0 by -1){
        if(a(j)>a(j+1)){
          val temp=a(j+1)
          a(j+1)=a(j)
          a(j)=temp
        }
      }
    }
    a
  }
}
```

I have the above code supposedly implementing bubble sort in Scala. It is sorting the given numbers in the main but is it a well implemented Bubble Sorting algorithm?
Also what does this line of code mean in pseudocode: for(j <- (i-1) to 0 by -1){

I can't understand it.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example you have posted is basically a imperative or Java way of doing bubble sort in Scala which is not bad but defies the purpose of Functional Programming in Scala.. the same code can we written sorter like below (basically combining both the for loops in one line and doing a range on the source length)

```
 def imperativeBubbleSort[T <% Ordered[T]](source: Array[T]): Array[T] = {
    for (i <- 0 until source.length - 1; j <- 0 until source.length - 1 - i) {
      if (source(j) > source(j + 1)) {
         val temp = source(j)
         source(j) = source(j + 1)
         source(j + 1) = temp
      }
    }
    source
   }

Scala Flavor of bubble sort can be different and simple example is below
(basically usage of Pattern matching..)

    def bubbleSort[T <% Ordered[T]](inputList: List[T]): List[T] = {
      def sort(source: List[T], result: List[T]) = {
          if (source.isEmpty) result
          else bubble(source, Nil, result)
      }


    def bubble(source: List[T], tempList: List[T], result: List[T]): List[T] = source match {
          case h1 :: h2 :: t =>
              if (h1 > h2) bubble(h1 :: t, h2 :: tempList, result)
              else bubble(h2 :: t, h1 :: tempList, result)
          case h1 :: t => sort(tempList, h1 :: result)
    }
    sort(inputList, Nil)
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

The best way to figure out what a bit of Scala code does is to run it in the REPL:

```
scala> 5 to 0 by -1
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Range = Range(5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0)
```

So that code counts from `(i-1)` to 0, backwards.

More generally, `x to y` creates a Range from integer `x` to integer `y`.  The `by` portion modifies this counting.  For example, `0 to 6 by 2` means "count from 0 to 6 by 2", or `Range(0, 2, 4, 6)`.  In our case, `by -1` indicates that we should count *backwards* by 1.

As for understanding how bubble sort works, you should read the Wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubblesort) and use that to help you understand what the code is doing.

Answer (score 3):

This can be the shortest functional implementation of Bubble sort

```
/**
 * Functional implementation of bubble sort
 * sort function swaps each element in the given list and create new list and iterate the same operation for length of the list times.
 * sort function takes three parameters
 * a) iteration list -> this is used to track the iteration. after each iteration element is dropped so that sort function exists the iteration list is empty
 * b) source list -> this is source list taken for element wise sorting
 * c) result -> stores the element as it get sorted and at end of each iteration, it will be the source for next sort iteration
 */

object Test extends App  {
  def bubblesort(source: List[Int]) : List[Int]  = {
    @tailrec
    def sort(iteration: List[Int], source: List[Int] , result: List[Int]) : List[Int]= source match {
      case h1 :: h2 :: rest => if(h1 > h2) sort(iteration, h1 :: rest, result :+ h2) else sort(iteration, h2 :: rest, result :+ h1) 
      case l:: Nil => sort(iteration, Nil, result :+ l)
      case Nil => if(iteration.isEmpty) return result else sort(iteration.dropRight(1), result, Nil )
    }
    sort(source,source,Nil)
  }
  println(bubblesort(List(4,3,2,224,15,17,9,4,225,1,7)))
 //List(1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 7, 9, 15, 17, 224, 225)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  @tailrec
  def bubbleSort(payload: List[Int], newPayload: List[Int], result: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
    payload match {
      case Nil => result
      case s::Nil => bubbleSort(newPayload, List.empty, s::result)
      case x::xs => x.compareTo(xs.head) match {
        case 0 => bubbleSort(xs, x::newPayload, result)
        case 1 => bubbleSort(x::xs.tail, xs.head::newPayload, result)
        case -1 => bubbleSort(xs, x::newPayload, result)
      }
    }
  }
  val payload = List(7, 2, 5, 10, 4, 9, 12)
  bubbleSort(payload, List.empty, List.empty)
```